# Do I Need A XBOX Live Membership?

Tags: xbox-network, xbox-one

So I am thinking of buying a XBOX One instead of a PS4 and I would like to know, do I need a membership of any kind to play games online with my friends. Any help regarding this would be helpful Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. To partake in online multiplayer on an Xbox One requires Xbox Live Gold membership.

PS4 has similar requirements.

Comment: Also I have found that PSPlus is actually cheaper than Xbox Live

Comment: @Ben where? In UK they're the same price from the companies themselves.

Comment: I got the comparison off the stores. That is in Australia however.